# Why can I not call .values() on generic enum class?

Tags: generics, kotlin, enums

I know that calling .values() on an enum class gives an array of the enum cases. However it doesn't work with a generic enum class. Why is this, and what can I do to get the same functionality?

```
class EnumEditActivity<E: Enum<E>>() {    
    var value: E? = null
    var allValues: Array<E> = E.values()
}
```

If I call values() on a normal enum, it works fine:

```
enum class Gender {
    male, female
}

for (value in Gender.values()) {
    println(value.name)
}
```

prints:

```
male
female
```

Some answers suggest doing something like this:

```
enum class SomeEnum {
    one, two
}

class EnumEditActivity<E: SomeEnum>() {    
    var value: E? = null
    val values = listCases<SomeEnum>()

    inline fun <reified E: SomeEnum> listCases() = (E::class.java).enumConstants.toList()
}
```

This doesn't work because it's not dynamic: it will always just get the cases for SomeEnum, so there's no point having a generic class. You can't pass any other enum apart from SomeEnum into the class, because one enum cannot inherit from another.

I don't think this is possible in Kotlin. I'm now just defining the class so it requires you to pass in an array of the enum's cases in the class initializer:

```
class EnumEditActivity<E>(val values: Array<E>)
```

Comment: this question would have even more value, if it would use pure Kotlin, since your problem is not Android related! :)

Comment: Thanks, good point. Have removed the unnecessary Android code from the example

Comment: see my updated answer. Your idea with the `Enum` base class was the right direction already. Pls, do not put parts of answers in your original question, since it renders the other answer incomplete/obsolete. Only put comments to answers in the comment section of the particular answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you have to call the function into the instance, not the type, to do so you have to reify the type variable:

```
interface  VisualEnum {
    fun get(fromName : String)
}

enum class VisuelEnumSub(lowerName: String) : VisualEnum {
    A("a"), B("b"), C("c");

    override fun get(name : String) {
        VisuelEnumSub.values().filter { it.toString().equals(name, true) }
    }}

open class AppCompatActivity{}

open class EnumEditActivity<E: VisualEnum>(): AppCompatActivity() {
    inline fun <reified A:E> onCreate() = (A::class.java).enumConstants
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   EnumEditActivity<VisuelEnumSub>().onCreate<VisuelEnumSub>().forEach { println(it) }
}
```

result:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: .values() is a static function. For example, you'd call Gender.values() and get an array of enum cases. It doesn't work on an instance

Comment: @mef27 try with (E::class).values()

Comment: I tried the following but results in an unresolved reference error on values()

Comment: inline fun <reified E> list(): Array<E> {
        return (E::class).values()
    }

Comment: @mef27 give me a few mins Im trying something right now

Comment: Ok sure, thanks for trying. I think the issue is that you can't use the companion object of classes you pass in as generics

Comment: @mef27 I think maybe I got it, let me know

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't use that function within the class as it gives me the error "cannot use E as reified type parameter".

Comment: The two `E` type parameters in `EnumEditActivity` are unrelated and confusing.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are right, I changed it so it has more sense

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this by passing the class as a parameter (because `E` is a class type parameter and `reified` isn't available):

```
class EnumEditActivity<E: Enum<E>>(cls: Class<E>) {    
    var value: E? = null
    var allValues: Array<E> = cls.enumConstants
}

inline fun <reified E: Enum<E>> EnumEditActivity() = EnumEditActivity(E::class.java)

// call as
EnumEditActivity<YourEnum>()
```

Or with your

```
class EnumEditActivity<E>(val values: Array<E>)
```

you can use the standard [`enumValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-values.html) function:

```
inline fun <reified E: Enum<E>> EnumEditActivity() = EnumEditActivity(enumValues<E>())
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Enum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/index.html) is the common base class of all enum classes. You can use `Enum<*>` as upper bound for your generic type `T`. The type has to be refified (and therefore the function `inline`) because you need to access it.

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> enumValues(): Array<T> {
    // do something...
    return T::class.java.enumConstants
}
```

Given an enum:

```
enum class SomeEnum { One, Two }
```

The function can be called like this:

```
println(enumValues<SomeEnum>().toList())
```

and would return that:

> [One, Two]

Comment: The point of this class is that it will take in any enum and display a list of the possible cases. I can't inherit my enum from SomeEnum (enum classes can't inherit from classes) so I can't use this function.

Comment: You seem to be simply reinventing [`enumValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-values.html).

Comment: @Slaw true, it has the same signature, but the OP asked for such a function so that he can add custom functionality. I edited my answer to try to make that more clear. I didn't know there was such a function :D. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's `value.declaringClass.enumConstants` if you're fine without compile-time safety.

Comment: value is null at the point of initialising the class, and is only assigned when the user presses a button. So I can't actually use .declaringClass here